# Convert to ONNX model in Google Colab

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I try to load MLModel.zip and convert to ONNX model to be able to use in Python.
Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using SampleImageClassification.Model;

namespace consumeModelApp
{   
    class DataPoint
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)] public string Label { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(1)] public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    }

    class LookupMap
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }
        }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mlContext = new MLContext();
            var lookupData = new[] {
                new LookupMap { Key = "duongphangiac" },
                new LookupMap { Key = "gocvuong" },
                new LookupMap { Key = "none_hash_marks"  },
                new LookupMap { Key = "one_degree" },
                new LookupMap { Key = "one_hash_marks"  },
                new LookupMap { Key = "three_hash_marks" },
                new LookupMap { Key = "two_hash_marks" },
            };
            var lookupIdvMap = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(lookupData);

            var pipelineWithLookupMap = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion
                .MapValueToKey(new[] {
                    new  InputOutputColumnPair("Label", "ImageSource"),
                    },
                    keyData: lookupIdvMap);


            // Path to the TSV file
            var filePath = "/content/drive/MyDrive/hinhhoc/train_kyhieu_1/ImageLabel.tsv";

            // Define the data schema for the input data
            var inputSchema = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(DataPoint));

            // Load data from the TSV file
            var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<DataPoint>(filePath, separatorChar: '\t', hasHeader: true);
            
            // Your further data processing goes here
            
            // Load the trained model
            var mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load("/content/drive/MyDrive/hinhhoc/consumeModelApp_Onnx/MLModel.zip", out var modelInputSchema);

            // Fit the pipeline to the data
            var transformedData = pipelineWithLookupMap.Fit(data).Transform(data);

            // Convert the model to ONNX format
            using (var onnx = File.Open("mymodel.onnx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                mlContext.Model.ConvertToOnnx(mlModel, transformedData, onnx);
            }

            // Load the ONNX model and predict output
            var onnxModelPath = "mymodel.onnx";
            var onnxModel = mlContext.Model.Load(onnxModelPath, out var onnxModelSchema);
            var onnxPredictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(onnxModel);

            // Now you can use the onnxPredictionEngine for making predictions
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my dataset on tsv file. It included "Label" and "ImageSource". The issue is how to convert to ONNX model instead of MLModel.zip. Please help me this case. It tooks more than 2 weeks and I can not go on this project.

```
Label   ImageSource
one_hash_marks  /content/drive/MyDrive/hinhhoc/train_kyhieu_1/one_hash_marks/one_hash_marks_2.png
one_hash_marks  /content/drive/MyDrive/hinhhoc/train_kyhieu_1/one_hash_marks/one_hash_marks_3.png
one_hash_marks  /content/drive/MyDrive/hinhhoc/train_kyhieu_1/one_hash_marks/one_hash_marks_6.png
```

Here is my ouput when build code, I do not know how to fix it.

```
=======Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not apply a map over type 'String' to column 'Label' since it has type 'Key<UInt32, 0-6>'
   at Microsoft.ML.Transforms.ValueToKeyMappingTransformer.Bind(IHostEnvironment env, DataViewSchema schema, TermMap unbound, ColInfo[] infos, Boolean[] textMetadata, Int32 iinfo)
   at Microsoft.ML.Transforms.ValueToKeyMappingTransformer.Mapper..ctor(ValueToKeyMappingTransformer parent, DataViewSchema inputSchema)
   at Microsoft.ML.Transforms.ValueToKeyMappingTransformer.MakeRowMapper(DataViewSchema schema)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.RowToRowTransformerBase.GetOutputSchema(DataViewSchema inputSchema)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1.GetOutputSchema(DataViewSchema inputSchema, TransformerScope scope)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1.GetOutputSchema(DataViewSchema inputSchema)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1.GetOutputSchema(DataViewSchema inputSchema, TransformerScope scope)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1.Transform(IDataView input, TransformerScope scope)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1.Transform(IDataView input)
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxExportExtensions.ConvertToOnnxProtobufCore(IHostEnvironment env, OnnxContextImpl ctx, ITransformer transform, IDataView inputData, String[] outputColumnNamesToKeep)
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxExportExtensions.ConvertToOnnxProtobuf(ModelOperationsCatalog catalog, ITransformer transform, IDataView inputData, String[] outputColumns)
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxExportExtensions.ConvertToOnnx(ModelOperationsCatalog catalog, ITransformer transform, IDataView inputData, Stream stream)
   at consumeModelApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /content/drive/MyDrive/hinhhoc/consumeModelApp_Onnx/Program.cs:line 66
=
```